# Can we create a dictionary with in a list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have to create a list as follows :
name, roll no
   subjectno, subject type
   subject no, subject type

e.g.

```
name[0] = ron, roll no[0] = 12
        subjectno[0]=1, subject type[0]="english"
        subjectno[1]=12, subject type[1]="maths"

name[1] = elis, roll no[1] = 11
      subjectno[0]=1, subject type[0]="english"
      subjectno[1]=12, subject type[1]="maths"
      subjectno[2]=14, subject type[2]="physics"
```

I am not sure how to do this in C#.
I tried making a list of student info and then for subject no and subject type i tried to make a dictionary. 
I have written the code like this -

```
class Student
{


    public class StudentInfo
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public int rollno { get; set; }
        Dictionary<String, String> subjects;
        public StudentInfo(String name, int rollno)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.rollno = rollno;
        }
        public void addstudentinfo(string subjectno, string subjecttype)
        {
            if (subjects == null)
                subjects = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            subjects.Add(subjectno, subjecttype);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What C# classes do you have to define your objects?

Comment: Homework? Please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I would do. First create these two class

```
public class Student
{
    public int RollNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Student(int rNo, string name)
    {
        this.RollNo = rNo;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public Student()
    {
    }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectNo { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Subject(int sNo, string sType)
    {
        this.SubjectNo = sNo;
        this.Type = sType;
    }
    public Subject()
    {
    }
}
```

Then fill in the objects as follows :-

```
  Dictionary<Student, List<Subject>> studentLists = new Dictionary<Student, List<Subject>>();
  Student std = new Student() { RollNo = 11, Name = "John" };
  List<Subject> sbj = new List<Subject>() {new Subject(020, "Math"),new Subject(030,"English") };
  studentLists.Add(std, sbj);
```

Then iterate thru the Dictionary as follows:-

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Student, List<Subject>> item in studentLists)
    {
        sb.Append("Student No : " + item.Key.RollNo + "<br />");
        sb.Append("Student Name : " + item.Key.Name + "<br />");

        foreach (var subjects in item.Value)
        {
            sb.Append("Subject No : " + subjects.SubjectNo + "<br />");
            sb.Append("Subject Name : " + subjects.Type + "<br />");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create struct or class to contain student's info and than add it to `Dictionary<string, StudInfo>`, where `string` is student name as Key.

Class for storing student info:

```
public class StudInfo
{
    public int RollNum;
    public List<string> Activities = new List<string>();

    public StudInfo(int num)
    {
        RollNum = num;
    }

}
```

And its usage:

```
var dict = new Dictionary(string, StudInfo);
var info = new StudInfo(12);
dict.Add("Ellis", info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't clear, but it looks best to create a `Subject` class as well.

```
class Subject{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

From there, you can change `Dictionary<String, String> subjects` to a simple `List<Subject>` type. And change `addstudentinfo` method to take a `Subject` as a parameter.

You can further improve it by ensuring that only one instance of a particular `Subject` ever exists by modifying the `Subject` class (For example, to use the [Creator pattern](http://cs.armstrong.edu/hsu/Course/CSCI3321/PracticalSoftwareEngineering/html/ch10s05.html)).